# How to get the unmatching rows in 2 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry I wrote the question more clearly here:
[How to get the nonmatching rows in 2 tables in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161534/how-to-get-the-nonmatching-rows-in-2-tables-in-sql)

Thanks

Comment: You may use `not in` or `not exists`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses a `LEFT JOIN` between the `CHANNELS` and `SUBSCRIBERS` tables:

```
SELECT c.ChanID, c.name
FROM CHANNELS c
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS s
    ON c.ChanID = s.ChanID
WHERE s.ChanID IS NULL AND
      c.nickname = 'Jonny' AND      -- not sure about this condition
      s.nickname = 'Jonny'          -- or this one
```

Here is a visual of what the intermediate table looks like during the merge:

```
c.ChanID | c.name | s.ChanID
1        | first  | 1
2        | second | NULL       <-- the second and third channels don't match
3        | third  | NULL       <-- to anything in the SUBSCRIBERS table (IS NULL)
4        | fourth | 4
```

Comment: It isn't clear what is happening with the nicknames, your data/design may have a problem.  If the nickname checks make the query not work, then remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT CHANNELS.ChanID FROM CHANNELS 
    LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS ON CHANNELS.ChanID=SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID
    WHERE
    CHANNELS.type='public' AND
    SUBSCRIBERS.nickname='a'
```

Try this

Edited:
I didn't get the question properly. If you want to select rows that Jonny is not subscribing, use subquery like this.

```
 SELECT ChanID C FROM CHANNELS WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUBSCRIBERS S WHERE S.ChanID=C.ChanID and S.nickname='Jonny') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.ChanID,C.name 
from Channels c Left join subscribers s on 
c.ChanID=s.ChanID 
where s.ChanID is null
```

This should work other condition may not required.