# How to get the nonmatching rows in 2 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables: `CHANNELS` & `SUBSCRIBERS`, and I want to get rows from `CHANNELS` that do not exist in `SUBSCRIBERS` on some condition.

I tried the `INNER` and the `OUTER(LEFT) JOIN` but it didn't work for me and they both gave me the same answer which is not what I wanted.

The tables are something like this:

**CHANNELS** table:

```
CREATE TABLE CHANNELS 
(
     ChanID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     description varchar(500) NOT NULL,
     nickname varchar(20) NOT NULL 
           REFERENCES USERS(nickname),
     subscribersnum int NOT NULL
)
```

**SUBSCRIBERS** table:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSCRIBERS 
(
     nickname varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS(nickname),
     ChanID int NOT NULL REFERENCES CHANNELS(ChanID)
)
```

The foreign key `nickname` is taken from some other table called `USERS`

Let's say that in **CHANNELS** we have the following rows:

```
 CHanID |  type  |   name   | description | (createdby) | subscribersnum 
        |        |          |             |  nickname   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     public    first         hi          Matty         3
    2     public    second        hii         Rose          2
    3     private   third         hiii        Matty         2
    4     public    forth         hiiii       Lucy          5
```

and in `SUBSCRIBERS` we have:

```
nickname   |    ChanID
------------------------
    Jonny         1
    Matty         3
    Jonny         4
    Rose          3
    Rose          2
```

I want to select all the *public* channels' IDs and names that the user with the nickname "Jonny" is not subscribed to yet,so in the example above I want the query to return the two rows:

```
ChanId  |   name  
-----------------

   2       second
```

The queries that I did are like:

```
SELECT 
    CHANNELS.ChanID 
FROM 
    CHANNELS 
LEFT JOIN 
    SUBSCRIBERS ON (CHANNELS.type = 'public' 
                    AND SUBSCRIBERS.nickname = 'Jonny' 
                    AND CHANNELS.ChanID != SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID);

SELECT 
    CHANNELS.ChanID 
FROM 
    CHANNELS 
INNER JOIN 
    SUBSCRIBERS ON (CHANNELS.type = 'public' 
                    AND SUBSCRIBERS.nickname = 'Jonny' 
                    AND CHANNELS.ChanID != SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID);
```

But they did not do what I need.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to know whether records exist or not, use `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`. You want data from the table `channels`, so select from this table and have your conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select chanid, name
from channels
where type = 'public'
and chanid not in (select chanid from subscribers where nickname = 'Jonny');
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confound the join condition with the where condition.
Also there's a mistake in your expected result, the third channel should not appear according to your previous condition that only the PUBLIC type are expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHANNELS.ChanId, CHANNELS.name
FROM CHANNELS
JOIN SUBSCRIBERS on CHANNELS.ChanId = SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID
WHERE CHANNELS.type = 'public'
AND SUBSCRIBERS.nickname !='Jonny'
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: No. This gets you all channels that others have subscribed to, no matter whether Johnny subscribed to those channels or not.

Comment: @PaulDaubian , thanks for notifying me about the third channel, I fixed it ,but when I tried your code it gave me exactly as Thorsten Kettner said,any way thank you,I may need this query some how in my work

Answer (score 1):

You have been trying to apply the **anti-join pattern**, which you'd normally use when you experience performance issues with the straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` (which happens when the DBMS optimizer doesn't handle these adequately).

I've shown you how to write the straight-forward query. Thanks for accepting it :-)

For completeness sake I tell you here how to build the anti-join: An anti-join works thus that you outer-join the other table, but then dismiss all matches in the where clause, thus keeping the non-matches. This can lead to large intermediate results, but often performs still fast, because joining is what DBMSs can do best (especially young DBMS that don't optimize so well).

```
SELECT 
    CHANNELS.ChanID 
FROM 
    CHANNELS 
LEFT JOIN 
    SUBSCRIBERS ON  SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID = CHANNELS.ChanID
                AND SUBSCRIBERS.nickname = 'Jonny' 
WHERE
    CHANNELS.type = 'public' 
AND
    SUBSCRIBERS.ChanID IS NULL; -- keep only outer-joined records, i.e. non-matches
```

Comment: thank you so much ,I'm sure I'm gonna use this later, really thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Going to risk brickbats for a non-tested and decidedly not the most *efficient* solution, but after thinking about this some I believe the best way to approach it is to get all combinations, then see which ones aren't in the subscriber list:

```
    select distinct a.nickname,b.chanid
      from subscribers a
     cross join 
    (select chanid
      from channels 
     where type='public') b
    left outer join subscribers c
      on a.nickname=c.nickname
     and b.chanid=c.chanid
   where c.chanid is null
```

The cross join gives you *all possible subscriber combinations*. The trick, then, is to see if each one of those combinations exists in the subscriber table. That allows you to use the outer join and test for null on the right-hand side. Again, perhaps not the perfect or ideal solution, but I think it gets you what you need empirically. Again, *not* tested, but I believe the idea is workable.